# What is the difference when we use 'should' instead of 'If'?

Tags: word-order, word-difference

> 1. Should you be lucky to visit the Seoul, you will be happy.
> 2. If you are lucky to visit the Seoul, you will be happy.

What is the difference between the two sentences in meaning? And what is the reason we change the order of the sentence 'you should' into 'should you'?

Answer (score 0):

when there is a less possibility we can use "should" instead of "If".

In your sentence it means that there is a less possibility that you're lucky enough to visit Seoul.

Hope it helps!